# The resource cannot be found in Ajax function

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using C# asp.net mvc.
I wrote a Ajax function in my Home controller - > index.cshtml.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {       

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '@Url.Action("getAlerts","Home")',
            data: ({}),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#alertList').html(data);


            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });

    }); 


  </script>
```

this is my function in Home controller

```
public IList<tblInsurance> getAlertsIns()
        {
            var query = (from i in db.tblInsurances
                        where i.status == true && i.EndDate <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)
                         select i).ToList(); ;


            return query;
        }

        public string getAlerts()
        {
            string htmlval = "";


            var InsExpirList = getAlertsIns();


            if (InsExpirList != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in InsExpirList)
                {
                    htmlval += item.tblContractor.Fname + " " + item.EndDate + "<br />";
                }
            }

            return htmlval;
        }
```

But ther is error and it says " `The resource cannot be found`."

```
POST http://localhost:49368/Home/getAlerts  404 Not Found
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You probably need to decorate the controller action with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your controller action to accept `POST`s, you must decorate it with an attribute specifying that fact:

```
[HttpPost]
public string getAlerts()
{
    // ...
}
```

In this case, however, it seems like a `GET` request would be more appropriate (your action is called `getAlerts` after all). If that's the case you can omit the accepted verb, or use `[HttpGet]` instead. You would also have to change your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: '@Url.Action("getAlerts","Home")',
    /* ... */
});
```